# getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" error on testing with Jest

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-navigation, ts-jest

I am getting the following error in a test with jest:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

```
 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/utils/conditional.tsx:3:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators.tsx:3:1)`
```

jest.config.js:

```
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)',
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)',
    '**/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)',
    '**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)',
    '**/?(*.)(spec|test).ts?(x)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'react-dom': 'react-native',
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
...
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.1",
...
```

Similar problem in closed issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8856

Any fix for this?

Thanks in advance!